# "Which type of nuts ARE/IS the heathiest?"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

It seems that people overwhelmingly prefer to write

> Which type of nuts are the healthiest?

to

> Which type of nuts is the healthiest?

However, `type` is singular, so why isn't `is` the correct choice?

***Edit*** if you type these sentences with quotes into Google (phrase search), you'll see that the first one occurs about 3000 times on the web,  and the second one basically never.

Comment: Can you show some evidence of this overwhelming preference?

Comment: @Jim see update

Comment: Please add the link. Because I get [**16 results**](https://www.google.com/search?ei=6tT8XMalKYOasAe6vZ2QDg&q=%22Which+type+of+nuts+are+the+healthiest%3F%22&oq=%22Which+type+of+nuts+are+the+healthiest%3F%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.2108.5984..6340...0.0..0.81.147.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.s7lmlj2nLik) and...

Comment: ... I get [**33 results**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22which+type+of+nuts+are%22&ei=ftX8XIXeNpKukwWf7YyACw&start=20&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiFlb6Fj9ziAhUS16QKHZ82A7A4KBDy0wMIMg&biw=1315&bih=647) for "which type of nuts are" this appears to not support your claim.

Comment: @Mari-LouA when I click on your first link, Google says "About 3,060 results (0.36 seconds)" but it only shows 1.5 pages of results. If I replace "are" with "is", there are no results aside from those linking this page. So 3,000 seems in error (by Google), but there are still more usages of the first version.

Comment: OK, so where's the link that shows the 3,000 hits?

Comment: @Mari-LouA You can't compare "which type of nuts are" to "which type of nuts is the healthiest" -- the number of words changes.

Comment: You claimed, and I quote "you'll see that the *first* one [i.e. Which type of nuts are the healthiest?] occurs about 3000 times on the web," Reducing the number of words from 7 to 5 should actually *increase* the number of hits. The essential elements are "type of nuts" and "are", it doesn't matter what adjective  follows. I could ask ‘Which [type of] nut(s) are the best/most expensive/cheapest’ the search item would include all of the variants "Which type of nuts are + adjective superlative"

Comment: @Mari-LouA well you reduced it in one case and failed to reduce it in another. Disingenuous, wasn't it? I already explained the 3000 above.

Answer (score 1):

You could always change the sentence so that it's not so confusing:

> 1. Which ***type*** of nut ***is*** the healthiest?
>   2. Which ***types*** of nut ***are*** the healthiest?

Note that *nut* remains singular in both cases, making subject-verb agreement easy. (It's when you use the plural *nuts* that things get awkward.)

Comment: The meaning is not preserved though. Suppose there are two types. I might want to know which *type* is the healthiest.

Comment: Yes, I would probably go so far as to suggest that the phrase "type of nuts" , is not, in itself, idiomatic. One is speaking of a collective - like "breed of dog, species of ant, etc." "Which type of nut is..." is the obvious route to go.

Comment: @MaxB If there are two types, that's why **types** is plural. (You actually pluralized it in your own sentence.) The *of X* is extraneous to the actual subject, which is *type* or *types*. There is one type. There are two types.